# c# windows forms always on top of all programs on computer

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make my Windows Forms stay on top of all programs on my computer.

For example, if I click into a Google Chrome window, I still want the form to be prioritized above it. Is this possible to do?

Comment: As far as I know it can only be set as `TopMost` for other forms which I think only covers other winforms.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the `Form.TopMost`?

You can just add this to your form:

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

Another thing is that you can always put it on top (forcibly) is to make it a dialogbox:

```
this.ShowDialog();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: but ShowDialog will not work with Chrome as he asked in question.   I think `TopMost` is what he want..

Comment: Yup, I think so. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one property on `Form` `TopMost` you can set true / false.

True - it will be on top
False (by default) - thats why doesn't stat on top by default

[image]

of course you can set from code also as @mindOfAi suggested.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work. Any reason TopMost would not work properly?